# Java gui how to make it look better

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Javas base gui is very plane is there anyway i can make it look nicer  such as adding an image as a background or changing how the buttons look

Answer (score 1):

You can change the look and feel of the Java Application. This will chage the way the buttons and windows will look.

- The nimbus LaF [Nimbus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)
- Web LaF [Web LaF](http://weblookandfeel.com/)
- Napkin LaF [Napkin](http://napkinlaf.sourceforge.net/)
- Synthetica [Synthetica](http://www.javasoft.de/synthetica/)
  These are few that I remember